# Scala: reflect class with implicit param

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-reflect

I am trying to reflect a class with implicit param, how can I get the actual implicit param at runtime to obtain a instance of this class?

```
object Validator extends App {

  val between = Between(1, 3)

  println(getAnotherInstance(between))

  def getAnotherInstance[T: TypeTag](obj: T)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) = {
    val tpe = typeOf[T]
    val lowerTerm = tpe.member(TermName("lower")).asTerm
    val upperTerm = tpe.member(TermName("upper")).asTerm
    val lower = mirror.reflect(obj).reflectField(lowerTerm).get
    val upper = mirror.reflect(obj).reflectField(upperTerm).get
    val constructorSymbol = typeOf[T].member(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).alternatives.head.asMethod
    mirror.reflectClass(tpe.typeSymbol.asClass).reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol).apply(lower, upper, Ordering[Int]) // problem is the Ordering[Int]
  }
}

case class Between[T](lower: T, upper: T)(implicit order: Ordering[T]) extends ValidateAnnotation {

  def validate(name: String, value: T): Option[String] = {
    if(order.lteq(value, lower) || order.gteq(value, upper)) Some(s"$name is not between $lower and $upper") else None
  }
}
```

The actual type of implicit param Ordering[Int] is confirmed at runtime, is there a way to get the implicit parameter(maybe Ordering[String], Ordering[Date]) at runtime? So that I can pass it to apply method then obtain an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def getAnotherInstance[T: TypeTag : ClassTag : Ordering](obj: Between[T]) = {
  val tpe = typeOf[Between[T]]
  val lowerTerm = tpe.member(TermName("lower")).asTerm
  val upperTerm = tpe.member(TermName("upper")).asTerm
  val lower = mirror.reflect(obj).reflectField(lowerTerm).get
  val upper = mirror.reflect(obj).reflectField(upperTerm).get
  val constructorSymbol = tpe.member(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).alternatives.head.asMethod
  mirror.reflectClass(tpe.typeSymbol.asClass).reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol).apply(lower, upper, Ordering[T])
}

getAnotherInstance(Between(1, 3)).asInstanceOf[Between[Int]].validate("aaa", 10) 
// Some(aaa is not between 1 and 3)
getAnotherInstance(Between("a", "c")).asInstanceOf[Between[String]].validate("bbb", "z")
// Some(bbb is not between a and c)
```

or

```
def getAnotherInstance[T: TypeTag : ClassTag](obj: T) = {
  val tpe = typeOf[T]
  val lowerTerm = tpe.member(TermName("lower")).asTerm
  val upperTerm = tpe.member(TermName("upper")).asTerm
  val orderTerm = tpe.member(TermName("order")).asTerm
  val lower = mirror.reflect(obj).reflectField(lowerTerm).get
  val upper = mirror.reflect(obj).reflectField(upperTerm).get
  val order = mirror.reflect(obj).reflectField(orderTerm).get
  val constructorSymbol = tpe.member(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).alternatives.head.asMethod
  mirror.reflectClass(tpe.typeSymbol.asClass).reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol).apply(lower, upper, order)
}
```

or

```
def getAnotherInstance[T: TypeTag : ClassTag](obj: T) = {
  val tpe = typeOf[T]
  val lowerTerm = tpe.member(TermName("lower")).asTerm
  val upperTerm = tpe.member(TermName("upper")).asTerm
  val orderTypeArg = tpe.member(TermName("order")).typeSignatureIn(tpe).typeArgs.head
  val lower = mirror.reflect(obj).reflectField(lowerTerm).get
  val upper = mirror.reflect(obj).reflectField(upperTerm).get
  val constructorSymbol = tpe.member(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).alternatives.head.asMethod

  import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
  val order = mirror.mkToolBox().eval(q"Ordering[$orderTypeArg]")

  mirror.reflectClass(tpe.typeSymbol.asClass).reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol).apply(lower, upper, order)
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your advise. The 1st approach reports a compile error if T not mix in trait Ordering, that is good. However, Ordering is passed to getAnotherInstance, i can not know weather the instance i want  require an implicit param and the actual type of it. The following ones raise exception at runtime without compile error. So is it possible to generate implicit param in getAnotherInstance, meanwhile guarantee the compile error report during compile time?

Comment: @Ego could you provide example `getAnotherInstance(???)` that should compile and example `getAnotherInstance(???)` that shouldn't compile? Reflection works at runtime. Maybe you need macros if you want this to work at compile time.